# How do I get a specific value for json data in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I successfully imported string of selected row using vuetify DataTable.

Now selected contents are received state in vuex store.

[image]

This screenshot is my state.

I'm not sure how to get the "002" in the id.

This is my store.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  selectIDs: [],
});

export const getters = {
  getCharacterById: (state) => {
    var selection = JSON.stringify(state.selectIDs)
    var arr = JSON.parse(selection);
    return arr;

    // this is not working
    return arr.id
  },
}

export const mutations = {
  updateSelectIDs(state, selectIDs) {
    state.selectIDs = selectIDs;
  },
}
```

index.vue

```
<span> selectIDs: {{ getCharacterById }} </span>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getCharacterById']),
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `selectIDs` is an array. Which element of the array are you trying to get by `arr.id`? This will be working directly `state.selectIDs[0].id` (without unnecessary json encode-decode)

Comment: It's a simple solution. Thank you.